Code for scheduled backup of current Notebook. How can it be improved?
With the help of this answer to How to execute this time-stamped auto-backup function every N minutes? I cobbled together a method to backup time-stamped versions of the current notebook. This effort was in response to having files corrupted and losing work. This is not the best strategy for dealing with such problems (backups of late copies of the uncorrupted files were in the Version Control of Google Drive - I didn't realise it had it till today!).
In any case, from clever tweaks and optimizations, to "nuke the code from orbit, it's the only way to be sure", how could it be improved?
(* Time-Stamped Backups *)

(* NB: Best declared as an Initialization Cell, which appear with \
gray BG *)

(* Periods and repeat count for the initial, shorter save period. *)
periodInitial = Quantity[15, "Minutes"];
(*should take it to 3.5 hours*) 
countInitial = 10;
periodAndCountInitial = {periodInitial, countInitial};

periodContinuous = Quantity[4, "Hours"];

(*Capture the notebook's file name before the scheduled task*)
originalFile = NotebookFileName[];
Print["originalFile=", originalFile];
evaluationNotebook = EvaluationNotebook[];

(*Path to backup directory*)
(*Good for testing*)
saveDirectoryPath=$TemporaryDirectory;
(*Define the backup function with originalFile as a parameter*)
backupNotebook[originalFile_] := 
  Module[{sec, name, fileName, fname, pathName, evaluationNotebook},
   sec = StringSplit[
      ToString@
       NumberForm[AbsoluteTime[], 10, 
        ScientificNotationThreshold -> {-10, 10}],
      "."
      ][[1]];
   name = FileNameTake[originalFile, -1];
   fileName = StringSplit[name, "."][[1]];
   fname = StringJoin[{fileName, "-", sec, ".nb"}];
   pathName = FileNameJoin[{saveDirectoryPath, fname}];
   Export[File[pathName], evaluationNotebook];
   ];

taskInitial = 
  SessionSubmit[
   ScheduledTask[backupNotebook[originalFile], periodAndCountInitial]];

taskContinuous = 
  SessionSubmit[
   ScheduledTask[backupNotebook[originalFile], periodContinuous]];

(*Start the tasks*)
TaskExecute[taskInitial];
TaskExecute[taskContinuous];

(*Mark them to be closed on notebook exit*)
SetOptions[en, 
  NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> 
     TaskRemove[taskInitial]}];
SetOptions[en, 
  NotebookEventActions -> {"WindowClose" :> 
     TaskRemove[taskContinuous]}];

It comes with two companion cells to kill the scheduled tasks.
Kill taskInitial:
(* Kill the initial task. Will fail after initial period \[Times] \
count. *)
TaskRemove[taskInitial]

Kill taskContinuous:
(* Kill the continuous task. *)
TaskRemove[taskContinuous]

